# Log variable base with variable

Tags: logarithms

Looking for help with this equation. Trying to help boyfriends younger sister but answer is either all numbers or its impossible:
$$
\log_x \left(x^5\right) = 5
$$

Comment: No that is the question. They want to solve for x.

Comment: As long as $x$ is any valid log base, that will be true.

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be an exponential function, and $f^{-1}(x)$ be its inverse, a logarithm. Then $f^{-1}\circ f(x) = x.$

Comment: I believe the answer is for all $x\in(0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\log_b a$ is really asking to which power do we need to raise $b$ to get $a$, in other words $\log_b a = x \iff b^x = a$. Therefore,
$$
\log_b \left(b^5\right) = 5
$$
for all $b$ where the log is defined.

Comment: Thanks I knew I wasn't going crazy. This was a question in the first section on logs before they have learned any log laws.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the fundamental rule of $\log$s. $$\log_a(b)=c\iff a^c=b$$

It also requires $b>0$.

In other words, you seek all $b>0$ such that $b^5=b^5$. This is trivially all $b>0$